# Arm Template - Bad JSON content found in the request

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add access policy to KeyVault with Arm Template But I am getting an error "Bad JSON content found in the request"
Details:
InnerError:
Code: BadRequest
Message:
Error:
Code: BadRequest
Message: Bad JSON content found in the request..

I don't understand what is wrong with the template that I am using.

This is the Template that I am using:

```
{  
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
        "parameters": {
            "keyVault": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "resourceGroup": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "subscriptionId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "tenantId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "objectId": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "[concat(take(deployment().name, 50))]",
                "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
                "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroup')]",
                "subscriptionId": "[parameters('subscriptionId')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                "properties": {
                    "mode": "Incremental",
                    "template": {
                        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                        "resources": [
                            {
                                "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
                                "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVault'), '/add')]",
                                "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
                                "properties": {
                                    "accessPolicies": [
                                        {
                                            "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                                            "objectId": "[parameters('objectId')]",
                                            "permissions": {
                                                "keys": [
                                                    "get",
                                                    "list"
                                                ],
                                                "secrets": [
                                                    "get",
                                                    "list"
                                                ],
                                                "certificates": [
                                                    "get",
                                                    "list"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Your code in the question is missing a `{` as a very first character. The rest looks ok.

Comment: I do have { as the fisrt character , But I am getting this error

Comment: yeah, this looks fine, unless you are passing some garbage to parameters

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Comment: Hi @AdyM, really glad that your issue has been solved. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add some access policy to an existing Azure Key Vault, I modified your template as below:

```
{
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
    "parameters": {
        "keyVault": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tenantId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "objectId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [{

            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVault'), '/add')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
            "properties": {
                "accessPolicies": [{
                        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                        "objectId": "[parameters('objectId')]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "get",
                                "list"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "get",
                                "list"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "get",
                                "list"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

I have tested on my side by PowerShell, it works as excepted.
Result:

[image]
[image]